# zsh shell: Copy/Paste on Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

In bash, used to simply Cmd+c and Cmd+v and press Enter to execute some previously tried command. This isn't working on zsh. Is there a simple trick to enable the previous method or any other alternative?

Comment: I launched a `zsh` in a terminal window where I was running Bash (i.e. I typed `zsh` to a Bash prompt).  I was able to use the trackpad to highlight text, Command-C to copy the highlighted material and Command-V to paste it at the `zsh` prompt, and then hit Return to activate it.  My gut feel is that your problem is more related to your terminal than to `zsh`, though I've been wrong before.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, "return" solved it.. I was trying to use the "enter" key from the number keyboard and that wasn't doing anything. Return key is working. Strange, did not see this behavior in bash..

Comment: I don't have a keypad enter key to check, but it's possible that Readline (`bash`'s command-line editor) and `zle` (`zsh`'s command-line editor) are configured to handle it differently (that is, `zle` differentiates between Enter and Return, but Readline does not).

Comment: I tried to reproduce the behaviour, but to no avail: In zsh, on both iMac and PC, the Enter key on the numeric keypad works the same as the return key. What happens if you type in zsh a command (instead of pasting it), and then press Enter?

Comment: @user1934428 That does not work too. I am trying this on a MBP connected to a Thunderbolt Display and apple keyboard (having both return and enter).

Comment: Looks then like chepner's guess is on the right track: First, your zle and readline basically seem to treat the keys differently, and then your keypboard seems to uncover theses differences. I did my tests with an (older) Apple keyboard on an iMac, connected via USB. Do you have a chance to try your keyboard with a different Mac (not MBP), as this also could make a difference?